# How do I Return Null Value of an Entity in Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

So I'm trying to return a null value for position in the database because I am creating an Employee archive in my code.

I was wondering how do I return a null value for POS_IDX in the database using Hibernate/Java/Springboot.

```
public class EmployeeEntity{

@Id
@Column(name = "EMP_IDX")

private Long id;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)

@JoinColumn(name = "POS_IDX", referencedColumnName = "POS_IDX")

private PositionEntity position;
```

Comment: Hello abe, could you show the Service/Controller using this entity and better describe what you want to achieve please?

Comment: Check out the [@Nullable](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters) annotation.